# partial derivatives $x^y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

Question: Find the first-order partial derivatives and second-order partial derivatives for: $f(x,y) = x^y$

I understand $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = yx^{y-1}$

Can someone explain why $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x^{y}\log{x}$

Comment: If you have a single variable function $f(y) = a^y$, where $a$ is some constant how would you take its derivative?

Comment: Hint: $x^y = e^{y\log x}$ <- to short for anwser v_v

Comment: It's just the rule for exponentiation.  Think about the derivative of 2^y.  It is ln(2) 2^y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a partial derivative you hold one variable constant while you differentiate with respect to another.
So
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x^y\ln x
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\frac{\text d}{\text dx}a^x=a^x\ln a
$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let

$$f(x,y) = x^y=e^{y\log x}$$

and use

$$[e^{g(y)}]'=e^{g(y)}\cdot g'(y)$$